# IE overflow: hidden generates a new line

Tags: css, internet-explorer, overflow, hidden

[image: On the left Chrome, on the right IE]

On the first image there is Chrome rendering
On the right there is IE.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="field">
        Mapname:
    </div>
    <div class="value" style="width: 102px;">
        Russia
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="field">
        Gamemode:
    </div>
    <div class="value"  style="width: 98px;">
        Samp-Rp.Ru Russia
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, internet explorer instead of cut off the extra text puts the div.value box down div.field.

Here my css:

```
div.field{
    float: left;
}

div.value{
    float: right;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: right;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div.row{
    min-height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: What happens when you increase the width from  `style="width: 98px;"` to a larger value say 110px or more?? Does it accommodate in IE??

Comment: Could you please make a live demo on JSFiddle? That will really help.
Also, we need to know IE version. My first guess is that adding `zoom:1` to `.row` and `.row *` might help (for IE 7,8).

Comment: Also, you can try to limit width by adding `max-width:98px;`

Comment: the problem here I think has nothing to do with overflow and whether it's on IE or Chrome. The problem is when the `.row` is too narrow and cannot accommodate the `.field` and the `.value`, The `.value` will be pushed down.

Comment: I changed width with max-width and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

The world of IE is a mystery and a pain, However the official [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh771902%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) source suggests using

`-ms-overflow-style: auto | none | scrollbar | -ms-autohiding-scrollbar`